# File not found in script module in Ansible

Tags: bash, ansible

I have a file called check_version.sh which basically checks for the package version if installed and echo it back.

Using ansible If i run that, I get the below error :

> ```
>     "/bin/sh: 1: /home/<username>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1530783607.87-161498766237862/check_version.sh: not found"
> ```

check_version.sh

```
testSoftwares="ruby redis mongo elasticsearch kibana openssh openssl nodejs"

for item in $testSoftwares
do
    result=`dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep $item | awk -F ' ' '{print $2"  "$3}'`
    if [ -n "$result" ] 
    then
        echo $result
    fi
done
```

While I have other files too which works perfectly fine. Not able to debug why this error occurs on this specific file.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of `check_version.sh: not found`?

Comment: the error refers the script is missing. Show the relevant part of the playbook, do you copy the script during the playbook before executing it ?

Comment: He should have copied the playbook, right. But he's probably using the `script` module https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you forgot to upload your script or sth like that. But for that purpose you should more likely use a ansible module/ ansible facts. Thats what they are for.
Following code as an example:

```
---

- hosts: all
  vars:
    yourPackage: "GeoIP"
  tasks:
    - package_facts:
        manager: "auto"
      register: packages
    - debug:
        var: "packages.ansible_facts.packages.{{ yourPackage }}"
```

That way you can operate directly in Ansible.